# Why string variable print with garbage

Tags: c++, string, pthreads, gnu

I wrote the following simple program to understand threads. In the result there are some garbage characters - why are these characters appearing? I'm using GNU G++ compiler in Fedora 17.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#define THREAD_COUNT 5

struct Man
{
 char name[10];
 int age;
 std::string address;
};


void* ThreadTask(void* man)
{
 Man *my_man = (Man*)man;
 std::cout << "Address of the person: " << my_man->address << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
 pthread_t threads[THREAD_COUNT];
 Man men_list[THREAD_COUNT];

 for(int i=0; i<THREAD_COUNT; i++)
 {
  strcpy(men_list[i].name,"nayana");
  men_list[i].age = i;
  men_list[i].address = "Singapore";

  int rc = pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,ThreadTask,(void*)&men_list[i]);
  if(rc)
  {
  std::cout << "Error while creating the thread" << std::endl;
  }
 }

pthread_exit(NULL);
return 0;
}
```

**Result:**

```
Address of the person: Singapore�0+���*��!      ����Singapore�0��▒s�!��t��s���E��t��s���EI
                                                                                          Address of the person: Singapore�0;s��:s�!�w       ����Singapore�0+���*��! ����Singapore�0��▒s�!��t��s���E��t��s���EI


                                       Address of the person: Address of the person:
```

Comment: where do I force to convert?

Comment: This application actually even crashes for me... Fwiw, the plural of man is men in English, not mans.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: thank you for the English lession :). Anyway This program compile and runs fine in gcc 4.6.3

Comment: You should wait until the threads finish executing, not `pthread_exit` prematurely.

Comment: @WiSaGaN: you may read this http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure that all the threads run before `men_list` goes out of scope and the memory is reclaimed.

This is not what `pthread_exit` does -- rather it terminates the calling thread.

The `pthread_exit(NULL)` at the end of your `main()` is not accomplishing anything sensible. Even though the man page says that exiting the main function with `pthread_exit` will "allow other threads to run to completion" (as you refer to in the comments), this doesn't mean that the scope of the main function won't end when the function does, nor does it mean that the other threads will run to completion *before* `pthread_exit` returns.

You can use `pthread_join` to wait for a thread to run to completion. To wait for all your threads to run to completion, you could use something like this:

```
int main()
{
  pthread_t threads[THREAD_COUNT];
  Man men_list[THREAD_COUNT];

  for(int i=0; i<THREAD_COUNT; i++)
  {
    strcpy(men_list[i].name,"nayana");
    men_list[i].age = i;
    men_list[i].address = "Singapore";

    int rc = pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,ThreadTask,(void*)&men_list[i]);
    if(rc)
    {
      std::cout << "Error while creating the thread" << std::endl;
    }
  }

  for(int i=0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++)
  {
    pthread_join( threads[i], NULL );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not like this because it makes the threading needless. I would prefer using a mutex instead for the simultaneous read/write.

Comment: @svk: Simply you mean middle of the programe `men_list` goes out of the scope right? So  If I replace `my_man->name` or `my_man->age` instead of `my_man->address` everything works fine. Why is that?

Comment: @LaszloPapp A mutex would with another problem (simultaneous read/write, as you say), which I don't think we're observing the effects of here. You'll still have this problem if you add a mutex, surely? I don't think there's a way to make the threading useful without changing the essence of the "hello world"-like example.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya When you invoke undefined behaviour, a perfectly valid outcome is for what you intended to happen to happen. It's just bad practice to rely on that.

Comment: I do not think the essence has to be changed. It is IMO reasonable to execute three threads for reading. You need mutex for that, and you need to wait for the threads to quit properly, but you should not make it blocking per thread.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I'm not sure I understand your objection (beyond that this example also lacks a mutex for safely sharing stdout). Can you elaborate? If we wait for the threads to quit properly, then we need to block `main` in some way or other until all the threads quit. Is your objection to joining the threads in a specific order? I can't see how that's relevant, since it doesn't impose any ordering on when the threads _run_.

Comment: As written before, you should _not_ block per thread without entering the next which your code wrongly does IMO. A wait condition, or a join should happen _after_ the loop and _before_ the current _exit_ place. Moreover, as written above simultaneous read/write from different threads is not atomic in C++, especially not for complex types like std::string.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I think I see the misunderstanding. You read my post as recommending doing a `pthread_join` within the already existing loop, right? Edited to clarify what I meant.

Comment: svk, indeed, it looked like you would make the threading useless with the previous revision. :D I would still add the mutex to the code to be complete.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: there's no simultaneous read/write to objects from separate threads in the answer's example. I don't see any need for a mutex.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: the main thread is modifying the same variable (men) while another is reading from it even if there is no overlap, and std::cout is not atomic either.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Isn't there a "danger" of the output being interleaved, e.g. "Address of Address of the person: Singa the person: Singaporepore"?

Comment: @svk and @ LaszloPapp: you are right about writing to `cout` - I overlooked that. Concurrent reads/writes to different elements of an array (`men_list`) is permitted without synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Also I see synchronization issue. You need to synchronize the common resource whenever you are using threads. Here common resource is std::cout. one way could be put the printing code under some synchronization object. then you will have everything printed in order.

Comment: See the intention is to guide him not spoon feed the person.

Comment: Posting inapplicable code isn't "guiding" them, it's just misleading. If they aren't familiar with the difference between the Windows and pthread API, they might waste a fair amount of time on your goose chase.

Comment: Made some changes. Is it okay now?

Comment: @BhupeshPant: you are mixing up two different threading APIs. I agree with Chris about misleading rather than "guiding". If you do not know pthread, fair enough, leave a comment about your theoretical idea, but this answer does not really make the code work, of course, not even compilable.

Comment: No, it is still not okay. You still use the "critical section" term which is windows-y. I would just write thread synchronization. In any case, the right answer will be to use a synchronization primitive like mutex.

Comment: @BhupeshPant: thank you for the idea, Actually in begin I also thought this may be a sync issue. but If I replace  `my_man->name` or `my_man->age` instead of `my_man->address` everything works fine. So I guess this should be something unique to string?

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya if that works for you please let me know, by ticking my answer or by doing plus 1, :). I have already earned -1. :(

Comment: @BhupeshPant: you have not even provided any code to make the OP's code work, but already asking for selection, +1, and crying for the -1? :)

Comment: @SChepurin: the main thread is writing those variables while the other threads may be reading the variable. This is not guaranteed to be atomic by the standard.